# Error message in Nav

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the error message I'm getting. Developed a theme using underscores. Just transferred the site from local to live. Any ideas why I'm getting this error? I'm getting this instead of Nav menu items

> WARNING
>   : MISSING ARGUMENT 2 FOR SO_37823371_MENU_ITEM_CLASS() IN
>   /HOME/MARSHA13/PUBLIC_HTML/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/MARSHALL/FUNCTIONS.PHP
>   ON LINE
>   168

Here's the line in question

```
 function so_37823371_menu_item_class ( $classes, $item, $args, $depth 
 ){
 $classes[] = 'menu-li';
 return $classes;
 }
```

Any idea's why my menu items aren't showing up?

Comment: Where you are calling the `so_37823371_menu_item_class` check if you are passing the right number of parameters(4)

Comment: @Hackerman I believe so

Comment: @Hackerman it would appear that you are not passing it a proper array of `$args` Let's see how you are calling this function.